# how to add "NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES" back to the "Log on as a service" permission

Tags: windows

How can I add "NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES" back to the "Log on as a service" permission? By default it is the only thing in "Log on as a service". It can be removed, but not added back with the local group policy editor. I have an image created by someone else with different stuff in that permission and not having NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES appears to be creating trouble for an application installer.
This is Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

The Powershell script here will do it: https://www.codykonior.com/2015/11/16/rebuilding-the-log-on-as-a-service-list-after-it-has-been-overwritten-by-group-policy/
Basically, it uses secedit.exe to do it.